# CodeIgniter - How to SELECT all rows in a big table without memory leake

Tags: php, codeigniter, activerecord

It's kinda hard to undertsand my need in the title.

CodeIgniter is performing a SELECT query in a table of 800,000+ rows in one shot.

It takes a lot of memory, but in one specific server, I get a "Out of memory" fatal error.

For performance purposes, I would like to seperate the select into 2 selects, and more specifically, the 50% first rows, and then the 50% left.

I reuse this set of data to perform an INSERT afterwise.

How to do that without losing/forgetting any single row ?

Comment: why you dont use limit and offset

Comment: Why do you need 800k rows in a single query? This sounds like an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: @KumarPraveen I'm looking for a codeigniter query style that selects all rows in two times, but LIMIT seems like you have to specify the exact number you want, and I don't know that number

Comment: You'd have to do a COUNT() query first to know the number of rows, and then divide it up. But again why do you want _two_ selects, exactly? This seems somewhat arbitrary. And as Grumpy mentioned, it's a **lot** of rows. Even half that (400,000) is still a very very large number of rows to select into an application. Why do you need so many rows all at once? What are you trying to do? I can't imagine any scenario where you'd need or want to show all the data to a user, for example.

Comment: @GrumpysaysReinstateMonica My issue is that I get a memory leake because of this big SELECT, so I need perform the select at least two times so that the serve don't gets out of memory

Comment: @ADyson Let me explain : I perform a SELECT on every rows of a table of an external server. Then, I perform an INSERT of this set of data in our own database. It runs with a cron every night to keep the data updated on our side

Comment: For this volume of data, this sounds like something which might be better solved with replication or some other related database technology. File-based dumps and then a LOAD DATA command would probably be a) faster and b) less of a memory problem. Code might just be needed to SFTP the dump file from the remote server or something. Use the right tool for the job. PHP is not a large-scale data transfer tool.

Comment: Just because I'm a semantics nazi, I'd like to point out that your problem is not a memory leak (which translates to memory not being released correctly after it's not needed anymore) but a simple memory exhaustion problem. You're loading more data into memory than your memory can handle (and yes, I'm aware that a memory leak eventually may lead to memory exhaustion, but the terms are not interchangeable)

Answer (score 2):

Beside the fact that operations like that are highly connected to performance issues, you can use `unbuffered_row`.

> Basically, if you have a job with that large data - you should use
>   `unbuffered_row` provided and integrated in the built
>   in query builder.
>
> its very well documented [here](https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/results.html#result-rows) in the result rows section.

for example:

```
$query = $this->db->select('*')->from('your_table')->get();

while($row = $query->unbuffered_row())
{
    //do your job
}
```

This will avoid your memory problem.