# Best Query to retrieve data from two large tables in Codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, sql, codeigniter

I am working on a laundry management system and want to retrieve customer order details with customer name from two tables having 25000+ rows of data. My code is working fine but using joins its taking too long to fetch the result. Kindly help me optimize the query. thanks
here goes my code that works fine buts takes more than a minute to return the data and almost crashes most of the time...

```
$this->db->select('users.first_name,customer_order.auto_id, customer_order.invoice_no, customer_order.order_date, customer_order.order_place_from, customer_order.customer_id, customer_order.total_qty, customer_order.discount, customer_order.disc_amt, customer_order.total_paid, customer_order.total_balance, customer_order.delivery_date, customer_order.amt_paidby, customer_order.order_status, customer_order.mode_of_payment_adv, customer_order.advance_paid, customer_order.mode_of_payment_bal, customer_order.balance_paid_date');
$this->db->from('customer_order');
$this->db->join('users', 'customer_order.customer_id=users.id');
$this->db->order_by("auto_id","desc");
$data['invoiceorder'] = $this->db->get()->result();
```

Limiting the record gives accurate timing but I need to fetch all records

Comment: you can use `limit` and `offset`, you mention you need all record then also limit and offset is best option

Comment: @DevsiOdedra can you please explain a bit more?
I'm not getting it.

Comment: if you need all data, you have to explain the background - because if you need it for a gui - then its totally nonsense to do that - if you need it for a cron then it may help to take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59665243/codeigniter-how-to-select-all-rows-in-a-big-table-without-memory-leake/59666355#59666355

Comment: @sintakonte yes actually I am working on a maintenance project don't know who created this scenario,
 this record is going to be used in a gui where data tables are being used for pagination, search and file conversion.

Comment: then you have to change your datatable structure to server side processing - take a look at https://datatables.net/examples/data_sources/server_side and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47885399/datatable-with-ajax-is-not-working-well-after-use-serverside-true - this should help you

Comment: If using joins is too slow with a 25.000 row table, you definitely need to stop looking at code-based workarounds and start looking as table indexes and stuff like that

Comment: @JavierLarroulet, I tried that too but indexes didn't work for me, I guess i'll need to go with server side programming as per sintakone in the above comment

Comment: @ZeeshanAhmad what do you mean "indexes didn't work for me"? did you correctly index your tables and still not getting good speeds on your queries? Could you share an `explain` on your queries?

Answer (score 0):

Use codeigniter pagination, limit records so it will work fast.
https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/pagination.html